# Google place search markers not showing on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I'm coding a demo of how I want a future search function to work. I want to query google on an address or area and return the area bounds as well as nearby places. To do this, I am using places autocomplete, geocode, and places search.

So far I am successfully getting predicted search queries resulting in the bounds being drawn as a rectangle on my map. However, when I try to implement markers for the place search result no markers are appearing on my map. I know the search is working because putting an alert in the createMarker function on each location returns several lat/lng's that coincide with my area.

I suspect that maybe the map object is not being passed to my createMarker function, but I am kind of a noob when it comes to Javascript. I tried passing an additional parameter but it didn't do much.

It should be noted that I am able to create a marker within the initialize function, when I attempt to just create one static marker.

EDIT: I have removed the type parameter for the place search request, but the code doesn't work even with the parameter ['store'].

```
var map;
var infowindow;


function initialize() {

var view_lat = document.getElementById('view_lat').value;
var view_lng = document.getElementById('view_lng').value;
var focus = new google.maps.LatLng(view_lat,view_lng);
var swlat = document.getElementById('swlat').value;
var swlng = document.getElementById('swlng').value;
var nelat = document.getElementById('nelat').value;
var nelng = document.getElementById('nelng').value;
var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas_embed');
var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(view_lat), view_lng),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var mysw = new google.maps.LatLng(swlat,swlng)

var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
var rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    bounds: new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
        new google.maps.LatLng(swlat, swlng),
        new google.maps.LatLng(nelat, nelng))
});
var request = {
    location: focus,
    radius: 500

};

var place_search = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
place_search.nearbySearch(request,callback)



}
```

Handles the result from google places search

```
function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    position: place.geometry.location
});
marker.setMap(map);
}
```

Autocomplete variables

```
var input = document.getElementById('location');
var options = {
    componentRestrictions: {country: 'se'},
    types: ['geocode']
}
var searchform = document.getElementById('searchform');
var place;
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Add listener to detect autocomplete selection

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    //console.log(place);
});
```

Add listener to search (This function isn't working, hence my work around in the initialize function)

```
searchform.addEventListener("submit", function() {
    var newlatlong = new       google.maps.LatLng(place.geometry.location.lat(),place.geometry.location.lng());
    map.setCenter(newlatlong);
    marker.setPosition(newlatlong);
    map.setZoom(12);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

});
```

Reset the inpout box on click

```
input.addEventListener('click', function(){
    input.value = "";
});
```

Call the initialize function

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Can you add this as a jsfiddle or something?

Comment: +1 for the JSFiddle. It's impossible to understand the interaction of your snippets otherwise. For example, in the `submit` event-listener your accessing a global variable `marker` which is not defined anywhere.

Comment: I'm trying to, but the demo is based on a python fed Jinja2 masterpage. I'll comment again if I manage to create a JSfiddle. I understand that the code interaction is hard to understand. I know the submit event listener is not working as it should, and this is not my main concern right now. I am mainly looking to know why my createMarker function isn't working.

Comment: [example of places search showing markers](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_10minuteDriveG.html) (no autocomplete though...)

Comment: When the code that you are talking about is the code starting with `searchform.addEventListener("submit",`....where do you cancel the  form-submission(which usually reloads the page)?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it looks like a problem of JavaScript's scope.

Consider these lines of your code:

```
    function initialize() {
      //...
      var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      //...
     }
```

Declaring `map` inside the `initialize` function makes your `map` variable unreachable out of your `initialize` function.

So when you try to reach it in your `searchform`, `map.setCenter()` will show in your console that `map` is undefined.

You could solve your issue in several ways.

1. declare `map` at the beginning of your script (before `initialize` is executed, anyways)
2. declare the `searchform.addEventListener("submit", function(){})` inside your `initialize()` function and use it before `initialize()` ends its execution.